# add a QListWidgetItem to a QListWidget using a std::shared_ptr to fix fortify issue

Tags: c++, qt, fortify, qlistwidget, qlistwidgetitem

Fortify doesn't like `QListWidget::addItem(new QListWidgetItem)` and reports a false memory leak, even though QT manages the memory properly.

I'm trying to figure out a work-around.
I was told to use a `std::shared_ptr`, but I haven't figured out the syntax yet.
Here's what I've got so far, but it reports an error about the type.

These 2 lines of code are all I need to fix, there is no further context.  Just looking for the syntax for a shared pointer to `QListWidgetItem`, adding the item to the list widget with `addItem()`.

Any syntax that works is fine.  MUST create a `QListWidgetItem` and THEN add it.  Cannot use additem("string") syntax.

In a header file, declare member variable item:

```
...
class Class1{
    ...
    std::shared_ptr<QListWidgetItem> item;
    ...
};
```

In a source file:

```
...
Class1::ClassFunction1()
{
  std::make_shared<QListWidgetItem> item("AStringToAdd");
  ui->qlw->addItem(item);
}
```

Comment: Syntax errors aside, I don't see how this is going to fix your problem: who owns the `QListWidgetItem` -- the `QListWidget` *or* the `std::shared_ptr`?  A better idea might be to make `item` an `std::unique_ptr<QListWidgetItem>` and then transfer ownership using `addItem(item.release())`.

Comment: @G.M. Writing that as an answer might not be a bad idea. Even if it does not make Fortify happy, it might make some other static analysis tool happy, so is worthy of having its own answer. If it works, it's indeed quite elegant (as much as making such stupid hacks to make analysis tools happy is ever elegant).

Comment: More generally, if Fortify can't handle Qt code, because Qt framework does its own ownership handling, then it's a bad tool for Qt code. If it is supposed to support Qt, please file a Fortify bug report or support ticket about `QListWidgetItem` (which is not a `QObject`). Otherwise, try to find a way how to disable this false positive from Fortify, instead of writing hacky work-arounds in your own code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might do the trick, based on code you show in your question:

```
class Class1{
    ...
    std::unique_ptr<QListWidgetItem> item; // no need to use shared ptr
    std::unique_ptr<...whatever you need here...> ui; // change ui to unique_ptr and put it after the item!
    // remember to change construction of `ui` accordingly, and remove deleting it in destructor
    ...
};

Class1::ClassFunction1()
{
  // reset member variable, don't create a new local variable
  item.reset(new QListWidgetItem>("AStringToAdd"));
  ui->qlw->addItem(item.get()); // pass naked pointer
}
```

That way, `item` will go out of scope before `ui`, and will be deleted by the `unique_ptr`. When the item is deleted, it will notify the view, and view will remove the item.

If you do it the other way around, view will delete the item, but it has no way to notify the `unique_ptr`. Therefore `unique_ptr` will delete it again, resulting in Undefined Behavior, with luck just a crash.

Comment: This is very close to what I've done - I used shared_ptr, still created the local.  The "get" solved the compile issue.  I might switch to using unique_ptr before I push the code.  Thanks!

Comment: Actually it turns out that fortify didn't like the reset.  I'm going to give make_unique a shot.

Answer (score 2):

As per my comment you might be able to utilize `std::unique_ptr` to silence fortify...

```
Class1::ClassFunction1 ()
{
  auto item = std::make_unique<QListWidgetItem>("AStringToAdd");

  /*
   * Use std::unique_ptr::release() to transfer ownership of the
   * QListWidgetItem to the QListWidget.
   */
  ui->qlw->addItem(item.release());
}
```

The solution provided in the answer by @hyde is certainly the more robust.  Having said that the original post is essentially seeking ways of trying to fix a problem with the fortify tool.  So the real solution is "fix the tool" or find other, better analysis tools.